# execute a service after a call ajax in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I need to save data in a service factory after a ajax call. It all works without location.href. But it doesn't work when I put the line code $window.location.href.
This is the code:

```
 scope.res = function(id){
            factoryService.getLista(id,"en-US","") 
            .then (function(response){commonVarService.setA(response.A);
                                      commonVarService.setB(response.B);
                                      commonVarService.setC(response.C);
                                      $window.location.href="./menu/menu.html";
                                     })
            .catch(function(err)  {console.log(err)});
        };
```

Where, factoryService allow to make an ajax call, wherease commonVarService allow to memorize data in variables of service.
If there isn't the $window.location.href="" it all works, but when there is the $window.location.href, the application redirect in the new page without memorize the variable.
where is it my Error? Is there some good solution?
Thanks in advance.

the commonVarService code is this:

> angular.module('common_variable',[])
>       .service('commonVarService',function(){
>
> ```
>         /*a*/
>         this.getA = function(){
>             return this._a;
>         }
>
>         this.setA = function(a){
>             return this._a=a;
>         }
>
>         /*b*/
>         this.getB = function(){
>             return this._b;
>         }
>
>         this.setB = function(b){
>             return this._b = b;
>         }
>
>         /*c*/
>         this.getC = function(){
>             return this._c;
>         }
>
>         this.setC = function(c){
>             return this._c = c;
>         }
>
> });
> ```

I also tried to put simply only the string as parameter:

> commonVarService.setA("A");
>   commonVarService.setB("B");
>   commonVarService.setC("C")

but when I'm in the new page.html of href link, the variable A , B, C are undefined...I don't know..

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: please provide the source code of setA, setB and setC function.

Comment: Hi, I put the code of set. It works, but when i put the $window.location.href="", it doesn't work. I don't understand why..

Comment: how do you define your route? is one of your route using menu.html?

Comment: no, I don't define a rout... I'm just following this: stackoverflow.com/questions/26594140/…... and it works.... but with href...dosen't save the data...I don't want to define a routing, is just a link with arrays of object to share between two different module

Comment: I think, the line code $window.location.href="./menu/menu.html" is called before the result of ajax...but I don't know how to resolve it....

Comment: FYI, it's generally a bad practice to use services as data repositories. There are some services that act as a _bus between_ you and a repository, which is fine, but they shouldn't really be the actual data destination.

Comment: @Harris : sorry.. but how can I share data between two modules of angular js?. I also tried ngStorage...but it doesn't work... it just create an array of empty object...I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

So, I am explaining the problem here,
When you are using`$window.location.href = 'something'`
 .
It does a full page refresh, so it cannot store the variable,reinstatiate a new angular instance.
i would suggest to use , angular-route or angular-ui-router , where you can change the route by using this , `$location.path('/profile')` or `$location.path('/mypage')` if you are building a SPA(Single page application) ,which will retain the state of your page.

Comment: Hi, I need to define a link in another page with another Angular js module, and they just need to share array of object...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594140/how-to-share-data-between-two-modules-in-angularjs.... is just in another page.html...

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with scope of variables when you are changing current page location it will load all js files again so it will also declare new variables

**"var service={}; var _a = null; var _b = null; var _c   = null;"**

Define above variables in **"localstorage"**

i.e. to **Set Value** : **localStorage.setItem("_a ", a);** 
     to **Get Value** : **localStorage.getItem("_a");**

Comment: I'm following this article...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594140/how-to-share-data-between-two-modules-in-angularjs... it works.... but when I put href ...the value are undefined...