# Passing id from one controller to another of different ng-app files

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 js files namely collegeApp.js and branchApp.js. I have two controllers CollegeController.js which is inside collegeApp.js ng-app and BranchController.js which is inside branchApp.js ng-app.

From my html I am redirecting to another page.

Here is my **html**

```
<li data-ng-click="getBranchByBranchId(branch.branchId); setBranchId(branch.branchId)">
    {{branch.branchName}}
</li>
```

This html page is in collegeApp.js.After clicking on branch name I am calling method And its controller looks like this.

**CollegeController.js**

```
var CollegeController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $route,CollegeService,$routeParams) {

    $rootScope.pageTitle = $route.current.title;

        $scope.getBranchId = function() {
        CollegeService.getBranchId().then(function(response) {
            $scope.branchId = response.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.setBranchId=function(branchId) {
      CollegeService.setBranchId(branchId);
    $rootScope.passBranchId = branchId;
      window.location.href="./branch?
      branchId='+$rootScope.passBranchId";//Here I am redirecting to branch page with id.//
    }
}
```

The branch page is in branchApp.js and above code is in collegeApp.js.
Now in BranchController.js I am trying to catch branchId sent from previous page.

**BranchController.js**

```
var BranchController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $route,BranchService,$routeParams) 
    {
      $scope.branchId = $rootScope.passBranchId;//Here i am trying to get branchId//
      console.log($scope.branchId);//I am getting undefined.
    }
```

I tried $rootScope,$routeParams.But none of them worked.
Is there any possible way that i can pass branchId from collegeApp to branchApp? or am i missing something?

Comment: I was going to suggest using a service to share data since this is their purpose, but you are already using one.  Why not just add `CollegeService` to `BranchController` and call `CollegeService.getBranchId()` in there?

Comment: Ok.I added CollegeService as a dependency in BranchController.Now in BranchController can i call directly getBranchId()?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why not.  the whole point of services to to be able to have shared logic/data between controllers/directives/components.

Comment: But as i am using two different app.js files when i add CollegeService as dependency in BranchController it is showing Unknown service provider CollegeService error although i have included CollegeService.js in branch index page

Comment: Oh, these are 2 totally separate applications?  That's another story all together.  I'm not sure it's possible to do what you want if you are using 2 entirely different applications

Comment: The application is same but i am having two app.js files

Comment: why have two application files for one application -- how is that even possible?  What's the advantage?

Comment: There is different design for College and branch.So on landing page CollegeApp.js loads.After clicking on branch then branchApp.js loads along with its different design homepage.

Comment: Sounds like just the CSS changes then?  Try to just use a single app.js file and you'll be able to share data as angular intended.  It sounds like you're making things very complicated for no good reason.

Comment: Do i have to go something with broadcast and on methods ??

Comment: no, just use a single aplication and you can easily share data with services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.I just added this line and it worked.

Inside SchoolController.js

```
    $scope.setBranchId=function(branchId)
    {
      window.localStorage.setItem("branchId", branchId); 
    }
```

And in BranchController.js

```
    $scope.branchId =   window.localStorage.getItem("branchId");
```

Now i am able to use Id anywhere in controller and also i am able to pass Id from collegeApp.js to branchApp.js ng-apps.

Answer (score 1):

When redirecting your page use `$location.path('/branch/' + branchId)`
Plus you already have `$location` in your controller.

Then you'll want to use  `$routeParams`  to find the id in your url.

Update route config to find params, should look like this

```
  $routeProvider
  ...  
  .when('branch/:branchId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/branches.html',
        controller: 'BranchController'
  })
```

Then get the value like so

`$scope.branchId = $routeParams.branchId;`

Comment: Do i need to add $location.path(branchId) in window.location.href?If so can u please tell how can i use it?

Comment: @SachinHR $location.path replaces window.location.href, it works the same, $location is part of the ngRoute module

Comment: But i am calling get and set departments on click and in setDepartment method i am using window.location.href.I am not using app.js to redirect

Comment: i gave location.path().Can i search outside folder in location.path()? like in window.location.href if we give ./ then it searches outside folder

Answer (score 1):

I realized that you wanted to share information between multiple modules within the same application. Here is a completed code sample to test the scenario.

```
/**
 * Service definition which holds the passed values
 */
angular.module('myapp')
.config('collegeService', collegeService);
collegeService.$inject = [];

function collegeService() {
    var branchId = null;

    return {
        getBranchId:    getBranchId,
        setBranchId:    setBranchId
    };

    function getBranchId() {
        /**
         * Implement a promise based approach if the branch ID reads from an external source
         * else just return it as given below
         */
        return branchId;
    }

    function setBranchId(brId) {
        branchId = brId
    }
}

/**
 * First controller definition
 */
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('CollegeController', CollegeController);
CollegeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'collegeService'];

function CollegeController($scope, collegeService) {

    $scope.getBranchId = function() {
        /**
         * Use promise based approach as below if the read method returns a promise
         */
        collegeService.getBranchId().then(function(response) {
            $scope.branchId = response.data;
        });

        /**
         * Uses a simple approach as below if the read method returns the value
         */
        // $scope.branchId = collegeService.getBranchId();
    };

    $scope.setBranchId = function(branchId) {
        CollegeService.setBranchId(branchId);
    }
}

/**
 * Second controller definition
 */
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('BranchController', BranchController);
BranchController.$inject = ['$scope', 'collegeService'];

function BranchController($scope, collegeService) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.branchId = collegeService.getBranchId();
    };

    /**
     * Invokes the init method during the Controller getting instantiated
     */
    $scope.init();
}
```

Comment: Does it work for multiple ng-apps?because i am trying to send branchId from collegeApp.js to branchApp.js

Comment: You mean a totally isolated apps which needs to communicate each other? FYI, a single app can have as many as modules which does independent things. The separation should happen if you need to completely isolate the apps.

Comment: Ok.But i am using two ng-app inside same project.Is it impossible then to communicate  between these two ng-apps in same project?

Comment: The isolated apps can communicate each other in multiple ways, one possible way is to use the server based variables through RESTful end points. The alternative non-recommended approaches will be use javascript to pass variables between apps.

Comment: Is there a reason why there are multiple apps running inside the same project?

Comment: ok thank you.I will try alternate ways of javascript like you mentioned.If you know any simple approach please let me know.

Comment: The simplest and the straightforward way is to embed those two controllers into the same application.